# How to handle disconnection/reconnection to the ROS master

Tags: ros, rosmaster, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a ROS node, just publishing to a topic, using roscpp that runs on a separate machine to the ROS master. It is based on the simple publisher/subscriber tutorials. If the ROS master gets restarted my node no-longer appears when I query the new master with rosnode list. It needs to be able to detect that the ROS master has gone down and re-advertise it's topics when it comes back up. I haven't managed to get this to work without killing and restarting my entire process.

I can detect that the connection to the ROS master has dropped by periodically checking ros::master::check () (would love a better way). When it returns true again after the master comes back up, none of the following work:

1. Call .advertise() on the old NodeHandle and get a new publisher.
   I thought this would work but it doesn't seem to.
2. Create a new NodeHandle and re-advertise on that.
3. Re-run ros::init
4. Call ros::shutdown and then call ros::init
   core dumps.

Also: I'm assuming ros::master::check () returns false if the connection is interrupted as well as if the master is restarted, do I need to handle that case differently or will re-advertising on the same master be OK?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202369/how-to-handle-disconnection/reconnection-to-the-ros-master/) by [techno74](https://answers.ros.org/users/20779/techno74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EpicZa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25859/epicza/) on 2018-03-21**:
Ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wrapping the ros::init() and NodeHandle creation seems to work. In a bigger project where I have passed the ROS nodeHandle around and attached publishers and things to it I can't get it to work yet.

### main.c

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include "rosConnection.H"

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool reconnect = false;

    do
    {
        rosConnectionHandler_t rc (argc, argv);

        ros::Publisher chatter_pub = rc.nodeHandle ()->advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

        ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

        while (ros::ok() && ros::master::check())
        {
            std_msgs::String msg;

            stringstream ss;
            ss << "hello world " << count;
            msg.data = ss.str();
            cout << msg.data << endl;

            chatter_pub.publish(msg);
            ros::spinOnce();
            loop_rate.sleep();
            ++count;
        }

        cout << "ROS OK: " << (ros::ok()?"true":"false") << endl;
        cout << "MASTER UP: " << (ros::master::check()?"true":"false") << endl;

        reconnect = !ros::master::check() && ros::ok();

        if (reconnect)
            cout << "Attempting to reconnect" << endl;

    } while (reconnect);

    return 0;
}
```

### rosConnection.H

```
#pragma once

#include <ros/ros.h>

class rosConnectionHandler_t
{
    public:
        rosConnectionHandler_t (int argc_, char** argv_)
        {
            ros::init (argc_, argv_, "testnode");

            nh = new ros::NodeHandle();
        }

        ~rosConnectionHandler_t ()
        {
            delete nh;
        }

        ros::NodeHandle *nodeHandle() { return nh; };

    private:
        ros::NodeHandle *nh;
};
```

---

Originally posted by [techno74](https://answers.ros.org/users/20779/techno74/) with karma: 90 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-03-30**:
This works but for some reason `ROS_INFO_STREAM`, `ROS_WARN_STREAM` and `ROS_ERROR_STREAM` does not seem to work after the first re-connection